# In jQuery, why is my $(this).next().removeAttribute not working?

Tags: jquery, html

I am doing a file upload form with the following buttons: "Choose file", "Upload" and "Add other file"

I am trying to remove the attribute "disabled" for Upload button when File Input change(). It works for the first Upload button, but not for the second Upload button and so on...
Why is that?

Thanks a lot if you could help me.

My jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
    $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
}); 

$('.add').click(function() {
    var num = $('input[type=file]').length; 

    newNum = num + 1;
    if (newNum >= 4){
        $('.add').hide();   
        }

    $('#addanother').append("<form method='POST'>");
    $('#photo1').clone().attr('id','photo'+newNum).appendTo('#addanother');
    $('#upload'+num).clone().attr('id','upload'+newNum).attr('disabled','disabled').appendTo('#addanother');
    $('#addanother').append('</form><br />');

    });
});
```

My html code is:

```
<form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file' class='fileinput' id='photo1'>

<input type='button' id='upload1' name='upload1' value='Upload' disabled='disabled'>
</form>

<div id='addanother'></div>

<input type='button' class='add' id='add1' value='Add file'>
```

Comment: Instead of removeAttr look at using prop() http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Hi Jay, I am looking into it. Thanks a lot. I find it quite confusing that removeAttr behaves like that. There is no logical reason for that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the 2nd upload button dynamically and so the event handler was not bound. Use `.on` in below syntax,

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=file]', function(){
    $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

and remove,

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
    $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: Yes it did work, I didn't know about on(), I am reading about this. thanks for that and for letting me know about the Accepted answer. Before I used to click on Yes for "Was this post useful to you?" but I was doing it wrong!
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Didn't realize you were modifying the DOM at first.

Replace

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
    $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

with

```
$(document).on({
    change: function() {
        $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}, 'input[type=file]');
```

Comment: Oh I see, that's the .on( events-map [, selector] [, data] ) syntax. +1